# finding Bit positions that devide a node into 4 nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, bit-manipulation

I have a root node (S1) with a range value say 1073741824 (min), 2147483648 (max). I am dividing this range into 4 equal ranges that represents 4 newly spawned nodes.The ranges for child nodes are respectively for (S2) 1073741824 (min), 1342177280 (max) ;for (S3) 1342177280 (min), 1610612736 (max); for (S4) 1610612736 (min), 1879048192 (max);for (S5) 1879048192 (min), 2147483648 (max). All the numbers are 32 bit in length. The attached figure could illustrate it more clearly :

```
  (S1) 1073741824 (min), 2147483648 (max)
  (S2) 1073741824 (min), 1342177280 (max)
  (S3) 1342177280 (min), 1610612736 (max)
  (S4) 1610612736 (min), 1879048192 (max)
  (S5) 1879048192 (min), 2147483648 (max)

  [Spawning 4 nodes from one node][1]
```

In binary the bounds are

```
S1 min = S2 min = 1073741824 = 01000000000000000000000000000000_bin
S2 max = S3 min = 1342177280 = 01010000000000000000000000000000_bin
S3 max = S4 min = 1610612736 = 01100000000000000000000000000000_bin
S4 max = S5 min = 1879048192 = 01110000000000000000000000000000_bin
S5 max = S1 max = 2147483648 = 10000000000000000000000000000000_bin
```

So if the numbers are represented in binary, is there any way to find the bit positions (from 0th bit position to 31st bit position) that divides the original range (1073741824 (min), 2147483648 (max)) into 4 equal sized groups? Is there any algorithm to do that?
For example I want to find 'i', 'j' th bit position (0<='i','j'<=31) so that 'i' & 'j' th bit divide
(S1) in to 4 equal ranges and the branching action to S2,S3,S4,S5 could be represented by ij=00,01,10,11.

Comment: In your example you would have to modify 4 bits (see my edit). Which bits to modify can found out by computing all bounds with the straightforward way and then combining them such that only the changing bits remain set in the result. The positions of these bits can then be extracted -- If you are interested in this, I can create an answer.

Comment: What are the constraints for S1? In your example S1_min is a power of 2 and S1_max = 2 * S1_min. If that is always the case, then it suffices to manipulate the two bits to the right of the (only) set bit in S1_min. If S1_min and S1_max have arbitrary values, then you essentially need to compute S1_min + (S1_max - S1_min) / 4, which can affect many (even all) bits.

Comment: Socowi, what you mean by “ changing bit remain set”? 
The 4 bits are the most significant bits based in your answer. ( b31.b30,b29, b28). If only min values are Considered for each node, don’t you think b28 and b29 would be sufficeient? 
I am interested in your answer

Comment: cătălin frâncu, the min and max values for S1 will be always power of 2 but S1_max won't be always equal to 2*S1_min. The number of cut for example in this case was 4, will also be a power of 2.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I wasn't notified on your comment. If you address a user please make sure to write `@user` instead of just `user` such that the user gets notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall thought …

> the branching action to S2,S3,S4,S5 could be represented by ij=00,01,10,11

… seems like premature optimization to me. Especially since you are using python which is not that fast to begin with. However, if you like to extract these bits for some other reason here is one way to do it. Please keep in mind that two bits are not sufficient in your example.

Which bits to modify can be found out by computing all bounds with the straightforward way and then combining them such that only the changing bits remain set in the result.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
min = 1073741824
max = 2147483648

# divide in the straight-forward way
diff = max - min
bounds = [min + i*diff//4 for i in range(5)]

# combine bounds such that only the changing bits remain set
changingBits = 0
for x in bounds:
    for y in bounds:
        changingBits |= x ^ y

print('bounds:')
for b in bounds:
    print('{0:010d} {0:032b}'.format(b))
print()
print('changing bits:')
print(' '*11 +  '{0:032b}'.format(changingBits))
```

This will print

```
bounds:
1073741824 01000000000000000000000000000000
1342177280 01010000000000000000000000000000
1610612736 01100000000000000000000000000000
1879048192 01110000000000000000000000000000
2147483648 10000000000000000000000000000000

changing bits:
           11110000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that for arbitrary numbers `min` and `max` you can get non-consecutive changing bits. Here is an example for `min=3` and `max=82589933`.

```
bounds:
0000000003 00000000000000000000000000000011
0020647485 00000001001110110000111000111101
0041294968 00000010011101100001110001111000
0061942450 00000011101100010010101010110010
0082589933 00000100111011000011100011101101

changing bits:
           00000111111111110011111011111111
```